# How to remove Avast website ratings

Tags: avast

How do I remove Avast website ratings from being all over the webpages and in firefox?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to Control Panel -> Add/Remove applications.
Select Avast and Change components. De-select the web reputation part.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open Avast → Additional Protection → Browser-protection → Expert Settings
2. Uncheck "Activate WepRep"
3. Click **OK**

Answer (score 0):

It changed again. Now you need to:

1. Right click the avast! icon in the task bar and select `Open avast! user interface`
2. Click The `Settings` link (to the right of the `Account` link at the top right)
3. Click on the `WebRep & Antiphising` tab in the left sidebar
4. Uncheck `Enable WebRep`
5. Click OK and restart your browser.

You can also go to the `Browser Integration` tab in the left sidebar and uninstall the `Security plugin` for each browser, which includes WebRep and sandboxing functionality.

This is current as of version 8.0.1497

Answer (score 0):

Removing Avast Site Rating Icon (WebRep) from Safari toolbar on MAC. Simply choose Safari>Preferences>Extensions,tap on Avast icon and hit uninstall. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for Firefox (25.0.1).

Disable or uninstall "Firefox" browser plugin: Avast online Security(some versionnumber).

Step by Step Guide:

1. Upper left corner check Orange button "Firefox" at Browser window.
2. Click "Add-ons".
3. Find "avast! Online Security (some versionnumber)".
4. Disable / Remowe.

I suggest "Disable" for saving option to use it sometimes and perhaps It gets User-Friendly update one day.